# How can I resolve this dependency issue with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData when installing via nuget?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget, breeze

I seem to have a dependency issue when trying to install this package.  I'm trying to figure out what I've messed up and how to debug this so I can make this all work.  The strange thing is that even though it says it failed to add the reference to System.Web.Http.OData, that reference shows up in the project after the failure.

The only thing I have installed on top of VS2012 is this update.

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (= 2.0.20710.0 && < 2.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (= 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (= 4.5.6)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (= 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.2.0 && < 6.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.2.0)'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnet_and_web_tools_2012_2_RTW_EULA_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.1'.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.0' from CrashBangZoom.WebApi.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Web.Http.OData'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

**EDIT:**

So, it seems like the above package for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData was already installed.  So, I removed that.  Now it complains about adding System.Spatial when I try to install the package for Breeze which requires the above library to work.

```
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'WebActivator 1.5.3'.
Successfully installed 'Q 0.9.2'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi 1.2.8'.
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Spatial 5.2.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Spatial'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Breeze.WebApi
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Looks related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314400/nuget-add-reference-error-while-installing-packages). Could you try the workarounds mentioned there?

Comment: Interesting.  I will give that first one a shot.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work.  Probably should have figured it wouldn't as I created a totally new solution and project and got package conflicts with that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had to just uninstall and reinstall VS2012 to get this to stop happening.  Not sure which dependency was messed up, but even deleting the packages and redoing them didn't help.