# NuGet: Failed to add reference to 'mscorlib'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm trying to add a .NET 4 libary to a .NET 4.5.1 solution with NuGet. This should generate the following entry in packages.config and reference the dll.

```
<package id="MyCompany.MyApi" version="2.0.1-alpha0680" targetFramework="net451" />
```

However, the error that I'm getting is:

> Error: Failed to add reference to 'mscorlib'.

What does work is the following:

- Add the NuGet package in packages.config
- Reference the dll in the packages folder manually

But obviously this is not my preferred solution.

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of the referenced question. This issue also occurs when I create a blank console application. So there isn't even a packages folder yet to clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314400/nuget-add-reference-error-while-installing-packages

Comment: Are you sure there is not a `<frameworkAssembly>` entry in the package pointing to mscorlib? If so remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing update 5 of Visual Studio 2013 the issue was solved. If someone knows why it would be nice to enrich this answer. Or create a new answer and I'll accept it.